# PDFBox - Losing Checkbox selection on "Save as" functionality of Dynamically filled PDF form

Tags: java, pdfbox, acrobat

I have an issue regarding a dynamically filled PDF form losing checkbox selection on using the Saves As functionality

I am describing the workflow which we are using currently to fill the PDF and subsequent issues.

1. We are receiving the PDF template created through "Adobe InDesign"  from a 3rd party vendor.
2. We are using "Apache PDFBox 1.8.X' utility to read the PDF form and fill in all the required fields .. including checkboxes and radio buttons.
3. Once the Filled up PDF is generated through PDFbox,   the PDF opens in a new browser window. All the selections are visible correctly as desired.

Scenario 1 > If i just save the generated PDF through save button on the browser , the PDF is saved correctly & all the checkbox selections are retained.
Also, when using Acrobar Pro to inspect the form fields, the check box fields are identified correctly.

**Scenario 2 ( Having issue )** >  In case of **using "Save As" either on the browser Or "Save As"** on the previously saved PDF on disk,   on saving ..   The checkboxes which were selected before displayed without the selections. **Also , the previously filled Check Box is also not recognized as a Form Field. Instead the checkbox is almost like a normal image / text almost** .

On a related note , i found that **i am able to view the checkbox selection when i open the "Save As" pdf it within Internet Explorer or another PDF utility other than Adobe Acrobat XI** . It seems to be an issue with PDFBox & Adobe Acrobat XI.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please share the pdf for analysis.

Comment: Since it's a client specific form , it's not allowed to share.  Let me check with the form creator if he can provide a test form similar to the one we are facing issue with.

Comment: Hi , Please find the attached files with the details in the readme which can help . Please let me know for additional details 
   https://github.com/hemanthgp1213/PDFDocument         @mkl

Comment: First of all, the differences between `PDF_Template.pdf` and the other two PDFs you shared make me doubt the latter ones are based on the first one. They probably are based on a newer or older version of the template. That been said, there is one big issue in the "Standard Account App (with checkbox).pdf" file - its abstract form definition (in the **Catalog** subdictionary **AcroForm**) contains no fields at all! The form fields are only referenced via their widgets on the individual document pages.

Comment: Such an incomplete form definition may cause any routine that tries to update form field appearances to damage the form information that still are left. Please check whether the actual template your PDFs are based on does have complete form definitions (or share that template to allow us to check). If it does, your code using PDFBox somehow throws away required data. This is not PDFBox behavior known to me, so please post enough of your code to allow us to point out where your code does so. If the template does not, the template you used already is erroneous.

Comment: I have uploaded the correct template revision ( **STRD_Template_v3.pdf**) from which the "Standard Account App (with checkbox).pdf" was generated. I opened the STRD_Template_v3.pdf template in PDFDebugger & there are many items under AcroForm > Fields:Array having Dictionary (Annot:Widget) . Can you check the template and confirm its its erroneous / fine . Also if its erroneous, what needs to be communicated to the PDF Design team so it can be resolved.             I am also working on getting permission to share the code which generates the filled PDF. i will update the same at the earliest.

Comment: The template looks fine. In particular (as you found out yourself) it contains the fields in its abstract form definition. The other file you added, though, i.e. `Standard Account App (checkbox)_Secure.pdf`, is even worse than the older `Standard Account App *.pdf` files, there is no **AcroForm** dictionary at all anymore. Furthermore, it is prefixed by a sequence of garbage bytes `¬í ur [B¬óøTà  xp úÊ` before the `%PDF-1.6` PDF header which invalidates the PDF.

Comment: Yes. I checked the issue. When the initial filled in file Standard Account App (checkbox)_Secure.pdf is generated, Acrobat is able to read the Fields/widget from within Dictionary (Catalog) > Pages . I have attached the screenshot in the github - Standard Account App (checkbox)_Secure.JPG .  We can see that the Checkbox details are correct and related to the Parent page. But when we do "Save as' , i can see that a empty acroform is added +  in the Distionary Catalog > Pages , the checkbox detail is changed in the sense , it is not related to any parent it is not being recognized as a checkbox

Comment: This issue is happening only to the checkboxes which were filled by PDFbox. The unfilled checkboxes continue to be recognized as same and related to Parent even after "save as".  So there are 2 issues for investigation .. issue 1 - why is the acroform removed during initial filling. And empty acroform is added on "Save As". issue 2 - Why are the checkbox not associated to parent page during "Save as".@mkl - Can you please help me if i can share the code which is generating the filled pdf & why the Acroform section is removed during filling and saving. pdf is sent as bytestream to UI & secure.

Comment: I have attached 2 screenshots showing the discrepancy in the checkbox details 1. Standard Account App (checkbox)_Secure.JPG         2. Standard Account App (no checkbox)_Secure.JPG    3. Standard Account App (no checkbox)_Secure.pdf

Comment: *"Can you please help me if i can share the code which is generating the filled pdf"* - sharing the code is necessary; otherwise I ca merely say that most probably you do something wrong in your code or less probably you found a bug in PDFBox.

Comment: Hi @mkl , i did not get permission to share the source code. But we found the root cause of the issue . The checkboxes filled by PDFBox are being lost in Acrobat reader DC when the "Save As optimizes for Fast Web View" is being checked under the Edit > Preferences > Documents > Save Settings . When we uncheck the check box , then we can see that the checkboxes are recognized correctly and Save As works without issues. I wanted to check with you if you have encountered such a scenario and if it can be resolved on the pdf template or pdf box end since we wont have control on client m/csettings

Comment: As mentioned before, that mostly sounds like a bug in your code or, less probably, a PDFBox issue, but in either case further analysis requires you to share a [sscce](http://sscce.org/), i.e. code and example data to reproduce the issue.